# Folder ID when creating folder using Box API

Tags: php, box, boxapiv2

I'm using the BoxPHPAPI and I was wondering if there was a way to get the folder ID when creating a folder?

https://github.com/golchha21/BoxPHPAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_folder` function returns the results of the Box folder creation call, which includes the `id` parameter. https://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-create-a-new-folder

```
$folder = $box->create_folder('FOLDER NAME', 'PARENT FOLDER ID');
print $folder->id;
```

Comment: Do a `print_r` of `$folder` and see what it contains.

Comment: Figured it out, needed to use `$folder['id']` . Thanks